# "TypeError: Parameters to generic types must be types. Got 0." in my function

Tags: python, typeerror

Ive written a function that counts how often a number smaller than my compared_number is in a list. But when executing it. I get the error in the title. Heres my function:

```
def count_smaller(input_list: List[int], compared_number: int) -> int:
    for l in List:
        if compared_number<0:
            break
        elif compared_number<List[l]:
            count+=1
            return count
```

Comment: what i forget to add is that it should ignore all numbers<0

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please post the full traceback in your question.

Comment: Please post the entire traceback, and expand the code to a [mcve]. This code should fail with a different error.

Comment: In your own words, what do you think `break` does?

Comment: In your own words, when you write `input_list: List[int]`, what do you think that means? When you write `for l in List:`, what do you expect `List` to be equal to, and where do you expect that value to come from?

Comment: Why are you bothering with typing?  That's a fairly advanced topic, and it doesn't seem like you're at that level yet.

Comment: break: stops the for-loop and lets the program continue afterwards.

Comment: I think input_list: List[int] means that the function expects the argument input_list to be a list with only integers in it. I now understood that i cant iterate over List but over input_list which actually is a list with values in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`List` is an object defining a type, not your actual list object. You can read more about type hinting in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#module-typing)

As you iterate over the list with  `for l in input_list`, use the element `l` of the list directly in your comparison :

```py
def count_smaller(input_list: List[int], compared_number: int) -> int:
    for l in input_list:
        if compared_number<0:
            break
        elif compared_number<l:
            count+=1
            return count
```

Comment: I know what you mean, but im importing "from typing import List" before the code lines in my question. I still get the same error when trying your answer.

Comment: I don't think you actually understand what I mean. Read the type hinting doc that I linked and probably the [python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/)

Comment: Thank you for your help I think I got it now. I overread that it says input_list and not List in your code. def count_smaller(input_list: List[int], compared_number: int) -> int:
    count=0
    for l in input_list:
        if compared_number<0:
            break
        elif l<compared_number:
            count+=1
            return count
print(count_smaller([-1,0,4],5))